# No handler for type [text] declared on field [title] (python elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch

all.
The python elasticsearch version I used is

```
import elasticsearch
print elasticsearch.__version__
(5, 0, 1)
```

the mappings is

```
request_body = {
    'mappings':{
        'post': {
            'properties': {
                'title': {
                    'type': 'text',
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error is :

> {u'status': 400, u'error': {u'caused_by': {u'reason': u'No handler for
>   type [text] declared on field [title]', u'type':
>   u'mapper_parsing_exception'}, u'root_cause': [{u'reason': u'No handler
>   for type [text] declared on field [title]', u'type':
>   u'mapper_parsing_exception'}], u'type': u'mapper_parsing_exception',
>   u'reason': u'Failed to parse mapping [post]: No handler for type
>   [text] declared on field [title]'}}

Why es 5.0 can not recognize the "text" type? What's wrong with my setup?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of issues in your mapping. Replace all the single quotes with double quotes and remove the `,` after the last line(field type definition.)

```
    {  
      "mappings":{  
        "post":{  
          "properties":{  
            "title":{  
              "type":"text"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! The error still exists!   elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: TransportError(400, u'mapper_parsing_exception', u'No handler for type [text] declared on field [title]')

Comment: The `text` type was only [introduced](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.x/mapping-types.html) in elasticsearch 5.x, are you sure you are on elasticsearch 5.x?

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I only install the python version.                            import elasticsearch
print elasticsearch.__version__
(5, 0, 1)    Should I install the java version ?

Comment: I check the es version, it's es 2.2.1 ?                                {u'cluster_name': u'elasticsearch', u'tagline': u'You Know, for Search', u'version': {u'lucene_version': u'5.4.1', u'build_hash': u'd045fc29d1932bce18b2e65ab8b297fbf6cd41a1', u'number': u'2.2.1', u'build_timestamp': u'2016-03-09T09:38:54Z', u'build_snapshot': False}, u'name': u'Lorelei Travis'}                                                       How can I get es 5.X  thanks!

Comment: @RaviNaik Is there any alternative for 'text' type in elasticsearch 2.x? I am stuck on the same error and have to use elasticsearch 2.x

Comment: As mentioned by Ravi, the text type was introduced in eslaticsearch 5.0 and the string type was removed in elasticsearch 6 : https://www.elastic.co/fr/blog/strings-are-dead-long-live-strings

Answer (score 2):

analyzer is mandatory for type:text. Refer https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to latest Elastic Search, I had some old version 2, there is now version 6 which supports [text]